# How to customize the text of "SUBMITTED BY" (article)

Tags: theming, 8

I like to customize the output of SUBMITTED BY, e.g. I like to change it to WRITTEN BY.
Where can I do it? Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need specifically for **ARTICLE Type**, just do apply change in `node.html.twig` template file(Here I am referring Bartik theme's node.html.twig for common understanding) as shown below. So for all other content type it will be `Submitted by` and for Articles it will be `Written By`,

**Original code in node.html.twig,**

```
    <span{{ author_attributes }}>
      {% trans %}Submitted by {{ author_name }} on {{ date }}{% endtrans %}
    </span>
```

**Replace it with,**

```
    {% if node.getType() == 'article' %}
       <span{{ author_attributes }}>
         {% trans %}Written by {{ author_name }} on {{ date }}{% endtrans %}
       </span>
    {% else %}
       <span{{ author_attributes }}>
         {% trans %}Submitted by {{ author_name }} on {{ date }}{% endtrans %}
       </span>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 5):

In node.html.twig change the line `SUBMITTED BY` to `WRITTEN BY`

```
  {% if display_submitted %}
    <footer class="node__meta">
      {{ author_picture }}
      <div{{ author_attributes.addClass('node__submitted') }}>
        {% trans %}Submitted by {{ author_name }} on {{ date }}{% endtrans %}
        {{ metadata }}
      </div>
    </footer>
  {% endif %}
```